# meaning of file .TSP (travelling salesman)

Tags: algorithm, format

I would like understand the informantion in a file .tsp found at:

http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/world/countries.html

For example

NAME : ar9152

COMMENT : 9152 locations in Argentina

COMMENT : Derived from National Imagery and Mapping Agency data

TYPE : TSP

DIMENSION : 9152

EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE : EUC_2D

NODE_COORD_SECTION

1 36266.6667 62550.0000 <- I don't understand? first row is the city and after?

2 34600.0000 58633.3333

3 51650.0000 72300.0000

4 37800.0000 67683.3333

Answer (score 4):

This file is in [TSPLIB](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/) format, documented in [this PostScript file](http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/DOC.PS). Since the instance type is `EUC_2D`, the line you pointed to is an x- and a y-coordinate. Officially, lengths are determined by rounding the Euclidean distance to the nearest integer.